# Slider Component not working properly in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a component where an array of values are presented like a slider, where every time, the old content gets replaced by a new one, and that can be done using the buttons next and previous. The component is working, but I'm struggling a little bit in the edge cases, where I have to disable the buttons

I'll leave the link to a codesandbox where the component is being built, I'm sure it'll be easier to understand what's going on.

[Link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-yalow-0bwiu?file=/pages/index.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to use state value for tracking button disabled status. Please check below.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const data = ["q", "c", "s", "a"];

  const [iterator, setIterator] = useState(0);
  const [curr, setCurr] = useState(data[iterator]);

  const fetchNext = () => {
    if (iterator === data.length - 1) {
      return;
    }
    setIterator((prev) => prev + 1);
    setCurr(data[iterator + 1]);
  };

  const fetchPrevious = () => {
    if (iterator === 0) {
      return;
    }
    setIterator((prev) => prev - 1);
    setCurr(data[iterator - 1]);
  };

  const nextDisabled = iterator >= data.length - 1;
  const prevDisabled = iterator <= 0;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{curr}</h1>
      <button disabled={nextDisabled} onClick={fetchNext}>
        next
      </button>
      <button disabled={prevDisabled} onClick={fetchPrevious}>
        previous
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you have to click twice to pass to the next letter, and the letter a doesn't show when you press Next, only if you press prevoius

Comment: @GabrielTiso Updated my answer.

Comment: I managed to get it working, but your solution works perfectly as well, thanks for the help :)